# Unit tests using Spark do not run any more from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I had to re-import my SBT project into IDEA, cleaned it thoroughly (`git clean -fdx`) and even did an "Invalidate caches / restart". Now, all my unit tests using the Spark context fail with:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.servlet.FilterRegistration"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

I already searched and dug around and found out that I have to exclude dependencies on `javax.servlet` on my dependencies on `hadoop-common`. I did this, but it did not help.

When running the tests from the console with `sbt test`, everything runs fine.

What can I additionally check?

EDIT: I even re-imported everything from scratch, including deletion of the .ivy2 folder, and it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the exclude for `javax.servlet` to ALL my Hadoop dependencies!